# solr 6.0 disable ocr for a specific core

Tags: solr, ocr, apache-tika, disable

I'm trying to disable OCR for a specific core.
i have solr 6.0 and I configured /update/extract the following way:

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="tika.config">C:\solr-6.0.0\contrib\extraction\lib\tika.config</str>      
    </lst>
 </requestHandler>
```

and file tika.config contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
  <parsers> 
  <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser">
      <parser-exclude class="org.apache.tika.parser.ocr.TesseractOCRParser"/>
    </parser> 
  </parsers>
</properties>
```

It doesn't work. I can't disable OCR. Any idea how to disable? (I have tesseract installed and I need it. Please don't suggest to remove it).
Thanks !

Comment: What does the list of arguments when you append `debug=all` to your query say? Does it include the `tika.config` argument? Does it complain if you give a non-existing file? Have you tried a newer version of Solr? Is the path correct?